# Overwrite option for dropbox filesUpload Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, dropbox

I am using following code snippet for uploading a file to Dropbox

```
dbx.filesUpload({path:"/"+file.name, contents:content})
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
```

This is working as intended but throwing a path conflict error second time onward because the file exists already. How can I set the overwrite option true in the `filesUpload()` ?

Answer (score 2):

[Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Specify-overwrite-option-while-uploading-file-using-javascript/m-p/225532#M12250 ]

You can specify the 'overwrite' [`FilesWriteMode`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/global.html#FilesWriteMode) in the [`FilesCommitInfo`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/global.html#FilesCommitInfo) passed to [`filesUpload`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#filesUpload__anchor) like this:

```
  dbx.filesUpload({path:"/"+file.name, contents:content, mode:'overwrite'})
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
```